# Cannot access udev symlink with python serial immediately on startup

Tags: python, udev, symbolic-link, serial-port

I have configured a udev rule to create a symlink for a USB device:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="3032", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0014", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB_GPS"
```

This creates a symbolic link `ttyUSB_GPS -> ttyACM1` (or `ttyUSB_GPS -> ttyACM0` depending on what else is plugged in).

I have a bash script that runs on startup and launches a python program via a systemd service. The python script uses the serial module to access the USB device, which I've set to be accessed through the symlink `ttyUSB_GPS` port. However, I get the following error when doing so:

```
Error: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

If I change the port in the python script to be the default `ttyACM1` and reboot then it works immediately on startup, but it may not always be this port value depending on what else is plugged in.

If I wait about a minute by putting a `sleep` command in the bash script before launching the python file, and using the port value `ttyUSB_GPS` then it works.

In the bash script I check the alias exists before launching the python script so I'm not sure why it doesn't function the same as accessing the ttyACM1 port directly.

What is it about the symlink that makes it not work immediately on startup? To my understanding, if the symlink exists then the operating system should treat it the same as the original port value.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you try debugging, record the output of `ls -l /dev/ttyACM* /dev/ttyUSB_GPS ; stat /dev/ttyACM* /dev/ttyUSB_GPS` in a log file from the script before trying to read from that port. It is possible that some programs are trying to probe it for that brief of time.

Comment: Did you ever solve it?